# Reading h2 tables by spark jdbc: NullPointedException

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, h2

I'm trying to read h2-tables by using spark jdbc in test scope.
This is my code:

```
 val url = jdbc:h2:~/test;USER=sa;PASSWORD=password  
 val user = sa
 val password = password 

 Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")
 val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)
 val statement = connection.createStatement

 statement.executeQuery("create table storage ( id integer, path text, name varchar);")
 statement.executeQuery("insert into storage values (1, 'test_path', 'test_name');")
```

I maked sure, that all data inserted into table.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("test-srark-jdbc").getOrCreate()

val props = Properties()
props.setProperty("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
props.setProperty("user", "sa")
props.setProperty("password", "password")
val storageDf = spark.read.
                jdbc(url, "storage", props)
```

And catch NullPointedException at last line: jdbc(url, "storage", props)

More concrete, exception catched in library method JDBCRDD.getQueryOutputSchema [JDBCRDD](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCRDD.scala), when trying connection.

```
 def getQueryOutputSchema(
  query: String, options: JDBCOptions, dialect: JdbcDialect): StructType = {
val conn: Connection = dialect.createConnectionFactory(options)(-1)
try {
  val statement = conn.prepareStatement(query)
  try {
    statement.setQueryTimeout(options.queryTimeout)
    val rs = statement.executeQuery()
    try {
      JdbcUtils.getSchema(rs, dialect, alwaysNullable = true,
        isTimestampNTZ = options.inferTimestampNTZType)
    } finally {
      rs.close()
    }
  } finally {
    statement.close()
  }
} finally {
  conn.close()   // conn = null !
 }
}
```

So, for some reasons connection is not created in JDBCRDD. At the same time option.url, option.table and option.driverClass passed to getQueryOutputSchema as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `org.postgresql.Driver` for PostgreSQL with JDBC URL of H2 Database?

Comment: Good question ) And this this is the cause of problem, indeed